# Memory for a member array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have been programming for a while today and I think I need a break because I can't seem to figure this very simple thing. A help will be greatly appreciated.

I have a class (actually `Form1`) and there a member array `int[,]f`.
Now I don't manage memory for it there and then (maybe I should?). 
Instead in another method, I call a function say:

```
myFunction(f,.....);
```

this function is like

```
void myFunction(int[,] f, ...some other arguments)
{
    //....
    f = new int[NX ,NY];
    //....
}
```

As you can see, I separate memory for the array `f` inside the function.

Now my question is; is this memory going to be garbage collected when I leave myFunction?

Comment: What does it have to do with `C++`?

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to understand a few very important things:

> Garbage Collection happens randomly.

Secondly,

> Only those objects that have no variables referring to them are eligible for GC

Thirdly,

```
f= new int[NX,NY];
```

You are making `f` refer to something else. The original `f` is still referenced by the `Form1.f`. But this `new int[NX, NY]` object is now created and referred to only by the local `f` in the method.

After the method returns, nothing should be referring to the new `f` (unless you assigned it to somewhere else), so the new `f` becomes eligible for GC. Note that I said "becomes eligible for GC" instead of "is garbage collected".

However, since `Form1` is still holding a reference to the original `f`, the original `f` will not become eligible for GC before the form does (unless you set it to something else).

Comment: so the f inside the function and the memory it managed do not refer to the Form1.f? Are they copies? ( I thought of them in terms of pointers being passed)

Comment: Yes you are passing pointers at first, until you do `f = new...`. At that point, `f` in the method refers to something else, while `Form1.f`'s value does not change. @KansaiRobot